# How to have form use a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I have 3 Models:

```
Location
belongs_to :user
has_many :products, :product_dates

ProductDate 
belongs_to :user, :location
has_many :products

Product 
belongs_to :user, :location, :product_date
```

I have a nested form:

```
<%= form_for @location do |first| %>
<%= f.fields_for :product_dates do |second| %>
<%= second.fields_for :products do |third| %>
```

I only have Two controllers but for my nested form am using ProductsController:

```
def new
  @location = Location.new
  3.times do
    product_date = @location.product_dates.build
    4.times { product_date.products.build }
  end
end
```

I want it to use my ProductsController because i need this Nested Form to redirect to Products/INDEX on save and not Locations/Show because my LocationsController is for creating Locations only and not many Products. How do i accomplish this?

**Note:** I have little Ruby and Rails experience.

Comment: You've defined `<%= form_for @location do |first| %>`, this says you want the LocationsController, but you want the ProductsController.
But maybe you should make a LocationsController, because your logic fit's much more into that controller.

Comment: But i have 2 forms, one for making Locations alone (locations/new) and then the nested form which creates Products (Products/new). Both use form_for @location but both redirect to locations/new. I don't want that i want the Products to redirect to products/index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have your form_for use a different controller you do:

```
<%= form_for @location, :url => products_path do |f| %>
```

If it is nested like my situation then you my also have your children fields do the same.

```
<%= f.fields_for :product_dates, :url => products_path do |date| %>
```

and

```
<%= date.fields_for :products, :url => products_path do |product| %>
```

Then i redirect back to my Products/INDEX:

```
def create
        @location = Location.new(params[:location])
        if @location.save
            redirect_to :action => 'index', :notice => "Successfully created products."
        else
            render :action => 'new'
        end
    end
```

Comment: Is the signal to use a different controller basically the last word in the resource name? Like the first will search for a controller related to "dates" and the second will search for a controller related to "products"?

Answer (score 1):

1) you can use nested routes instead:

```
resources :locations do
  resources :product_dates
  resources :products
end
```

2) model Location should has the accepts_nested_attributes_for

```
class Location < AR:BAse
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_dates, :products
end
```

3) controller should not build children object, because you can only initialize and save parent object, children will be saved automatically

Comment: This means i need the Product_dates controller and now all of my product routes are gone.

Comment: I edited my answer to give more insight on what i want to do this for.